# TypeScript not compiling when expression used as property name to acess function with an argument who's type has optional fields. TS2349

Tags: typescript, tsc

The following code will not compile in TypeScript 2.1.4 giving the error:

**Error**

> Error:(6, 31) TS2349:Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '((args: string[], action: A) => string[]) | ((args: string[], action: C) => string[])' has no compatible call signatures.

**Code**

```
/*
* Set up a function to take some arguments
* and an action and use the map to run the appropriate
* function bases on the type property of the action 
*/ 

const caller = (args: string[] = [], action): string[] => {
        return map[action.type] ? map[action.type](args, action) : args;
 };

interface Action {
    type: any; 
}

const TYPE_A = "type_a";

interface A extends Action {
    from: number;
    to: number;
    id?: number; // optional parameters causing the issue.
    prop1?: number;
}

const TYPE_B = "type_b";

interface B extends Action {
    from: number;
    to: number;
}

const TYPE_C = "type_c";

interface C extends Action {
    id: number;
    prop1: number;
}

const map = {
    [TYPE_A]: (args: string[], action: A) => {
        return ["a"];
    },
    [TYPE_B]: (args: string[], action: B) => {
        return ["b"];
    },
    [TYPE_C]: (args: string[], action: C) => {
        return ["c"];
    }
};

caller([], {type: TYPE_A, from: 2, to: 1});
```

**Motivation**

My motivation for using an expression as the property in the map is so that I can change the value of the property constants without needing to refactor the map.

**Solutions**

There are two ways of solving this:

**a)** Remove the optional fields in `interface A`.

```
interface A extends Action {
    from: number;
    to: number;
    id: number; // optional parameters causing the issue not optional.
    prop1: number;
}
```

**b)** Change the map properties declarations to values and not expressions and keep optional fields.

```
const map = {
    "type_a" : (args: string[], action: A) => {
        return ["a"];
    },
    "type_b": (args: string[], action: B) => {
        return ["b"];
    },
    "type_c": (args: string[], action: C) => {
        return ["c"];
    }
};
```

**Question**

My question is why is the error shown in the first place, can someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that `A` and `C` are incompatible because `prop1` is optional in `A` and required in `C`. So you can't use function that takes `C` in place where a function that takes `A` is needed:

```
let fa: (a: A) => void;
let fc: (c: C) => void;

fa = fc;
fc = fa;
```

errors:

```
test.ts(49,1): error TS2322: Type '(c: C) => void' is not assignable to type '(a: A) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'c' and 'a' are incompatible.
    Type 'A' is not assignable to type 'C'.
      Property 'id' is optional in type 'A' but required in type 'C'.
test.ts(50,1): error TS2322: Type '(a: A) => void' is not assignable to type '(c: C) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'a' and 'c' are incompatible.
    Type 'C' is not assignable to type 'A'.
      Property 'from' is missing in type 'C'.
```

When you declare a map with literal property names, type inference can figure out when you do `caller([], {type: TYPE_A, from: 2, to: 1});`, you are actually accessing a value with `"type_a"` key, so it knows that function parameter type is exactly `A`. It can't do that when map is declared with calculated keys, probably because it just does not evaluate expressions for keys at compile time, so it infers a union type for map values, and two members of the union are incompatible with each other because `A` and `C` are incompatible.

You can also get around this by just explicitly declaring type for `map`:

```
const map: {[key: string]: (args:string[], action: Action) => string[]} = {
    [TYPE_A]: (args: string[], action: A) => {
        return ["a"];
    },
    [TYPE_B]: (args: string[], action: B) => {
        return ["b"];
    },
    [TYPE_C]: (args: string[], action: C) => {
        return ["c"];
    }
};
```

also works.